# How can we configure load balancer for WSO2 2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The multi tenancy architecture described mainly refers to a scenario where a single instance of a Carbon server acts as a single multi tenant node. In a situation where a very high load of requests are handled, you may need multiple multi tenant nodes. In order to operate with multiple multi tenant nodes, you need load balancing. The load balancer you use also needs to be tenant-aware.            So how can we configure load balancer for WSO2 2.0 ?